# Proof $\min \{\cfrac{a}{a+b} , \cfrac{b}{1-a}\} \le \cfrac{a}{1-b}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Suppose that $0<a,b<1 \space$  s.t $\space a+b < 1$.

Prove $\min \{\cfrac{a}{a+b} , \cfrac{b}{1-a}\} \le \cfrac{a}{1-b}$.

Comment: False for $a=\frac14,b=\frac13$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\min \{\cfrac{a}{a+b} , \cfrac{b}{1-a}\} =\frac{a}{a+b}$, I have: $1-b\leq a+b$ that is true because $b>0$. In the other case, if $\min \{\cfrac{a}{a+b} , \cfrac{b}{1-a}\} = \frac{b}{1-a}$, I obtain: $(1-b)b\leq a(1-a)$ that is true because $a<1-b$ and $1-a>b$.